# Erro ao fechar Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código para fechar minha aplicação.

```
private void frmAgent_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{       

    if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente fechar o sistema?", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes) 
    {                
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Mas quando clico para fechar e clico em `sim` ele cai no `if`, executa o trecho `Application.Exit();` e retorna para inicio do método abrindo o `MessageBox` novamente. Se eu clicar em `sim` novamente, aí sim ele fechar o `form`. Alguém já viu isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere seu código como o exemplo abaixo

```
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente fechar o sistema?", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        != DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Ao usar [`Application.Exit();`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é disparado o método [`FormClosing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) e gera um loop.

No exemplo acima isso é evitado.

Comment: Jota, muito obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Dessa vez esse está fechando o winform, mas infelizmente o processo não é finalizado ao fechar a aplicação. O que pode estar ocorrendo ?

Answer (score 2):

Faz todo o sentido acontecer isto já que o [`Application.Exit()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.exit?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Application_Exit) conforme demostra a documentação dispara o evento que vai executar seu `frmAgent_FormClosing`. Quando chega neste método já se sabe que a aplicação está saindo, não precisa dizer que é para sair. Não precisa fazer mais nada. Isto deve resolver.

```
private void frmAgent_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {       
    if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente fechar o sistema?", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No) {                
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/CloseForm.cs).

Se você tiver que fazer algo mais, pode fazer mas se só queria fazer a confirmação, não precisa dizer para fechar, o fluxo normal se você não dizer que é para cancelar é fechar.

Antes de usar alguma coisa sempre leia o manual.

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual é o erro aqui para ter um -1?