# Processo não fecha no gerenciador de tarefas

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código para fechar minha aplicação winform:

```
private void frmAgent_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){          
        if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente fechar o sistema?", "Atenção!",    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            != DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

A aplicação fecha, mas infelizmente o processo ainda fica rodando no gerenciador de tarefas.
O que posso fazer para matar o processo ao fechar a aplicação ?

Comment: `frmAgent` é o único formulário da aplicação? Como está sua classe que contém o método `Main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia chamar o método `Environement.Exit(0)` que encerra diretamente o processo da sua thread corrente (sua aplicação no caso), por exemplo:

```
private void frmAgent_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{          
    if (MessageBox.Show("Deseja realmente fechar o sistema?", "Atenção!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) != DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }

    Environement.Exit(0);
}
```

Existe ainda a possibilidade de chamar o método `Application.Exit()`, que encerra todas as threads de sua aplicação e posteriormente o processo. Você pode testa-lo também. Recomendo a leitura [deste link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046019/winforms-application-exit-vs-enviroment-exit-vs-form-close).

Comment: Não poderia, ele estava tendo problema com isto. Este evento justamente é disparado porque ele está saindo da aplicação (ou pelo menos é o que parecia, de qualquer forma ele não pode sair desta forma). http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47890/101

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado Felipe Oriani !